# Using SQLAlchemy, how can I make a field in a class that is a list of other instances of said class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a user class as detailed below:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=128), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=128), unique=True)
    _password = db.Column("password", db.String(length=60))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    profile_picture = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=128), unique=True, nullable=True)
    twitter = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=256), unique=True, nullable=True)
    github = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=256), unique=True, nullable=True)
```

I would like to add another column to the user class which is a list of users. How can I accomplish this?

I think the proper name of what I am looking for is a self-referential one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Can a user belong to *multiple* parents?

Comment: Yes, basically what I am going for is a following field. So the following attribute of the class would be all the users that itself is following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you want to store a association table that stores which user follows which user(s). This is what is known as a *many-to-many* relation. Since a user can follow *many* other users, and a user can be followed by *many* users.

For that we need to **define an additional table**, and **`relationship`**(http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) to specify the usage of that table, for instance:

```
class UserFollows(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_follows'

    follower = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    followee = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Now we can define two *virtual columns* to the `User` class and specify that SQLAlchemy should look into the `user_follows` table for this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=128), unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=128), unique=True)
    _password = db.Column("password", db.String(length=60))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    joined = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    profile_picture = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=128), unique=True, nullable=True)
    twitter = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=256), unique=True, nullable=True)
    github = db.Column(db.Unicode(length=256), unique=True, nullable=True)
    followers = db.relationship('User', 
        secondary = followers, 
        primaryjoin = (UserFollows.c.follower == id), 
        secondaryjoin = (followers.c.followee == id))
    follows = db.relationship('User', 
        secondary = followers, 
        primaryjoin = (UserFollows.c.followee == id), 
        secondaryjoin = (followers.c.follower == id))
```

Now a `User` object has two attributes `followers` and `follows` which act as collections of users that store the persons the `User` `follows` as well as the `followers` of that `User`.